How can Kyomoto graduate school and publish in the school newspaper despite not attending classes?
In Look Back (2024 anime film), the character Kyomoto is described (in the English subtitles) as a "truant" and "shut-in" who "stopped going to school because [she] was scared of people."
Throughout the film, the protagonist Fujino never sees her at school, yet Kyomoto's four-panel manga regularly appears in the school newspaper—a significant plot element.
The film shows Kyomoto graduating elementary school (with Fujino tasked to deliver her diploma by a teacher) and later senior high school, presumably from the same school as Fujino.
This seems unusual since, in the educational systems I'm familiar with, regular attendance is typically required for graduation. Fujino and Kyomoto's school appears to be a public school, and it's unclear if Kyomoto is being home-schooled.
My research indicates that homeschooling is not legally permitted in Japan for children under the age of 14:

Mainstream education is compulsory for resident children up to high school age in Japan, meaning elementary and junior high school are mandated in the country. However, homeschooling becomes a legal and viable option once your child reaches 14 years old, as high school is optional.

- A Guide to Homeschooling in Japan. Beacon

Whilst mainstream education is compulsory for resident children up to high school age in Japan, it becomes a legal and viable option once your child reaches 14 years old.

- Homeschooling in Japan. Wolsey Hall Oxford
If Kyomoto is receiving education through the public school system while staying at home, how does this arrangement work? Is this a common practice in Japan for students unable or unwilling to attend classes?
Are there specific aspects of Japanese culture or its education system that explain this situation, or is there something lost in translation? How is Kyomoto able to both graduate and maintain involvement with school activities like the newspaper while not attending classes?

Many kids are absent from school due to physical or mental health problems, but are still officially enrolled

I believe the teacher mentions that she takes her classes by mail when he asks Fujino to deliver the diploma, but I do not specifically recall if they mention any further details.
